# Showing Affine maps are combinations.

Tags: affine-geometry

How do you show that an affine map can be written as sum of a linear transformation and a translation by a vector?

Comment: Isn't that the definition of an affine map? What's your definition?

Comment: An affine transformation is any transformation f:U→V for which, if ∑λi=1,
f(∑λixi)=∑λif(xi)
for all sets of vectors xi∈U.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?